# How to update Ubuntu when it errors?

Tags: apt

I typed `sudo apt update` to update all my programs on my computer and I get this error:

```
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
```

How do I fix it please?

Comment: Before adding PPAs you should assure they support your Ubuntu release. The one mentioned in the error doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, it seems the [PPA was abandoned](https://launchpad.net/~nilarimogard/+archive/ubuntu/webupd8) with Ubuntu version 21.04.

Comment: Thanks @Nmath, I tried typing `sudo ppa-purge https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu jammy Release` from the highlighted answer but the computer says `sudo: ppa-purge: command not found`

Comment: Thank you @ChanganAuto, I don't know how to do that though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error means that the ppa does not support your ubuntu release.

Look at the supported releases :

https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists

So remove that ppa to solve the issue.

Here a guide :

https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/12/how-to-remove-ppa-ubuntu

use the gui method, is more simple for a beginner.

Or you can do it with :

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
```

Comment: If I can't fix it does this mean I have to reinstall Windows please?

Comment: I've updated my answer.